# Проверить значение селекта, при фокусировке на любом поле формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, всплывающее-окно

У меня есть функция, которая вызывает модальное окно, с предупреждением.

Есть форма которую нужно заполнить, но прежде чем приступать к ее заполнению, нужно сначала выбрать категорию с помощью селекта.

Хочу реализовать следующее.

Если пользователь не выбрал селект, но нажал на любое из полей, т.е произвел фокусировку, то вызывалась функция модального окна.

Можно как то реализовать это, не прописывая функцию вызова окна каждому полю ? т.е что бы как то отбхватить всю форму целиком ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44745/discussion-on-question-by-stackoverfollow-----).

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь всплывающими событиями - https://habrahabr.ru/post/246837/.

```js
(function(document){
var form = document.querySelector('form'),
 select = form.querySelector('#category');

form.addEventListener('focus',focused,true);

function focused(e){
 var target = e.target;
 if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'input') return; //Обрабатываем фокус только на input'ах
 
 /*
 Элемент на котором сработал фокус находится в переменной target
*/
  
  
 console.log('focus', select.value);
  
}

})(document);
```

```html
<form>
<div>
  <select id="category">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text">
</div>
<div>
<input type="text">
</div>
</form>
```

JSFiddle - jsfiddle.net/1s3xsb95/

Comment: Не подскажите, как при вызове modal убрать с подвеску клавиатуры ? т.е к примеру если я вызываю модал окно, по клику или фокусу на инпут, то в телефоне автоматически вылетает "клавиатура для набора текста" как можно такое предотвратить ?

Comment: ```function focused(e){
 var target = e.target;
 if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'input') return; //Обрабатываем фокус только на input'ах
target.blur(); //Убираем фокус с поля

 
 /*
 Элемент на котором сработал фокус находится в переменной target
*/
  
  
 console.log('focus', select.value);
  
}```

Comment: Это что было то ? А понял, там просто в комментах код запрятался. Спасибо ! щас попробую